# Вопрос по aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

3дpacтвуйтe, меня интересуют есть ли на aiogram возможность создавать дроп даун команд там где нет бота? В общем, бота typeruzbot можно использовать и в личных сообщениях там где нету бота с помощью вот такой дроп даун менюшке, которая вызывается если упомянуть бота через `@`, вот меня и интересует эта менюшка.
[image: дроп даун менюшка]
Можете дать пожалуйста ссылки на документы от aiogram по это теме?

Comment: Это Inline бот. [Тут](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline) документация по ним

Comment: @ZxNuClear, спасибо